# Simplifying a block of code

Tags: javascript, arrays, image, colors

Is there a way to simplify this part of my code? I've been working on this and finally got this piece right or its doing what I need it to do. I have an array (6*6) and when you click on the image it turns all the other images around it the same color. I am only using red and blue and yes sorry I didn't use semicolons but I'll fix that later. So could anyone help me out? If you need the whole program I can upload that too.

```
function vClick(iRow, iCol)
{
    var i, j;

    if (astrColor[iRow][iCol] == 'r')
    {
        if ((iRow - 1) < 0)
        {
            for (i = iRow; i <= (iRow + 1) ; i++)
            {
                if ((iCol - 1) < 0)
                {
                    for (j = iCol; j <= (iCol + 1) ; j++)
                    {
                        var strID = "img" + i + "," + j;
                        document.getElementById(strID).src = 'rcircle.png';
                        astrColor[i][j] = 'r';
                    }
                }
                else if ((iCol + 1) > 5)
                {
                    for (j = (iCol - 1) ; j <= iCol; j++)
                    {
                        var strID = "img" + i + "," + j;
                        document.getElementById(strID).src = 'rcircle.png';
                        astrColor[i][j] = 'r';
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    for (j = (iCol - 1) ; j <= (iCol + 1) ; j++)
                    {
                        var strID = "img" + i + "," + j;
                        document.getElementById(strID).src = 'rcircle.png';
                        astrColor[i][j] = 'r';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else if ((iRow + 1) > 5)
        {
            for (i = (iRow - 1) ; i <= iRow; i++)
            {
                if ((iCol - 1) < 0)
                {
                    for (j = iCol; j <= (iCol + 1) ; j++)
                    {
                        var strID = "img" + i + "," + j;
                        document.getElementById(strID).src = 'rcircle.png';
                        astrColor[i][j] = 'r';
                    }
                }
                else if ((iCol + 1) > 5)
                {
                    for (j = (iCol - 1) ; j <= iCol; j++)
                    {
                        var strID = "img" + i + "," + j;
                        document.getElementById(strID).src = 'rcircle.png';
                        astrColor[i][j] = 'r';
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    for (j = (iCol - 1) ; j <= (iCol + 1) ; j++)
                    {
                        var strID = "img" + i + "," + j;
                        document.getElementById(strID).src = 'rcircle.png';
                        astrColor[i][j] = 'r';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else if((iCol - 1) < 0)
        {
            for (i = (iRow - 1) ; i <= (iRow + 1) ; i++)
            {
                for (j = iCol ; j <= (iCol + 1) ; j++)
                {
                    var strID = "img" + i + "," + j;
                    document.getElementById(strID).src = 'rcircle.png';
                    astrColor[i][j] = 'r';
                }
            }
        }
        else if((iCol + 1) > 5)
        {
            for (i = (iRow - 1) ; i <= (iRow + 1) ; i++)
            {
                for (j = (iCol - 1) ; j <= iCol ; j++)
                {
                    var strID = "img" + i + "," + j;
                    document.getElementById(strID).src = 'rcircle.png';
                    astrColor[i][j] = 'r';
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (i = (iRow - 1) ; i <= (iRow + 1) ; i++)
            {
                for (j = (iCol - 1) ; j <= (iCol + 1) ; j++)
                {
                    var strID = "img" + i + "," + j;
                    document.getElementById(strID).src = 'rcircle.png';
                    astrColor[i][j] = 'r';
                }
            }
        }            
    }
    else
    {
        if ((iRow - 1) < 0)
        {
            for (i = iRow; i <= (iRow + 1) ; i++)
            {
                if ((iCol - 1) < 0)
                {
                    for (j = iCol; j <= (iCol + 1) ; j++)
                    {
                        var strID = "img" + i + "," + j;
                        document.getElementById(strID).src = 'bcircle.png';
                        astrColor[i][j] = 'b';
                    }
                }
                else if ((iCol + 1) > 5)
                {
                    for (j = (iCol - 1) ; j <= iCol; j++)
                    {
                        var strID = "img" + i + "," + j;
                        document.getElementById(strID).src = 'bcircle.png';
                        astrColor[i][j] = 'b';
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    for (j = (iCol - 1) ; j <= (iCol + 1) ; j++)
                    {
                        var strID = "img" + i + "," + j;
                        document.getElementById(strID).src = 'bcircle.png';
                        astrColor[i][j] = 'b';
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        else if ((iRow + 1) > 5)
        {
            for (i = (iRow - 1) ; i <= iRow; i++)
            {
                if ((iCol - 1) < 0)
                {
                    for (j = iCol; j <= (iCol + 1) ; j++)
                    {
                        var strID = "img" + i + "," + j;
                        document.getElementById(strID).src = 'bcircle.png';
                        astrColor[i][j] = 'b';
                    }
                }
                else if ((iCol + 1) > 5)
                {
                    for (j = (iCol - 1) ; j <= iCol; j++)
                    {
                        var strID = "img" + i + "," + j;
                        document.getElementById(strID).src = 'bcircle.png';
                        astrColor[i][j] = 'b';
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    for (j = (iCol - 1) ; j <= (iCol + 1) ; j++)
                    {
                        var strID = "img" + i + "," + j;
                        document.getElementById(strID).src = 'bcircle.png';
                        astrColor[i][j] = 'b';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else if ((iCol - 1) < 0)
        {
            for (i = (iRow - 1) ; i <= (iRow + 1) ; i++)
            {
                for (j = iCol ; j <= (iCol + 1) ; j++)
                {
                    var strID = "img" + i + "," + j;
                    document.getElementById(strID).src = 'bcircle.png';
                    astrColor[i][j] = 'b';
                }
            }
        }
        else if ((iCol + 1) > 5)
        {
            for (i = (iRow - 1) ; i <= (iRow + 1) ; i++)
            {
                for (j = (iCol - 1) ; j <= iCol ; j++)
                {
                    var strID = "img" + i + "," + j;
                    document.getElementById(strID).src = 'bcircle.png';
                    astrColor[i][j] = 'b';
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (i = (iRow - 1) ; i <= (iRow + 1) ; i++)
            {
                for (j = (iCol - 1) ; j <= (iCol + 1) ; j++)
                {
                    var strID = "img" + i + "," + j;
                    document.getElementById(strID).src = 'bcircle.png';
                    astrColor[i][j] = 'b';
                }
            }
        }        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you need to change all the images around, and not only up, down, left, right. Also I'm assuming you will call vClick correctly (i mean only when needed). Finally, this work may not work perfectly since it is the first idea.

My idea is to iterate only once, from [i-1,j-1] to [i+1,j+1], and using a single function which will change the given item only if it exists.

```
function vClick(iRow, iCol)
{
 for (i = iRow-1; i<=iRow+1; i++)
   for (j = iCol-1; j<=iCol+1; j++)
        changeImage(i,j);
}

function changeImage(i,j)
{
 var strID = "img" + i + "," + j;
 var theImage = document.getElementById(strID);
 if (theImage != null)
   if (theImage.src == 'bcircle.png')
       {theImage.src = 'rcircle.png'; astrColor[i][j] = 'r';
   else
       {theImage.src = 'bcircle.png'; astrColor[i][j] = 'b';}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

[DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) Put same code blocks in helper methods and just call them.

It also will help the readability of your whole code, as right now, I can just tell you're doing a bunch of logic for whether columns and rows are in some value range.

To get better advice please explain exactly your algorithm (way of thinking) in plain English as I can honestly read nothing.

Comment: I have an array (6*6) and when you click on any of the image it turns all the other images around it the same color. I am only using red and blue.